# Discussion of specific arithmetic triangle groups?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, arithmetic-groups, fuchsian-groups, central-simple-algebras

Arithmetic triangle groups were classified in Takeuchi, Arithmetic triangle groups, J. Math. Soc. Japan Volume 29, Number 1 (1977), 91-106. The (2,3,7) case was discussed in detail in a number of places including the book by Maclachlan and Reid, p. 159-160, where one finds an explicit presentation in terms of a suitable quaternion algebra; and in papers by Elkies and others where the appropriate *order* is specified, as well, and congruence subgroups are studied. Are there any texts where other triangle groups are dealt with in detail, in particular with regard to congruence subgroups and the corresponding Riemann surfaces? I am particularly interested in the (2,3,8) case and the closely related (3,3,4).

Comment: Looks like Takeuchi gives more info. in another paper: http://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/dspace/handle/2261/7343